# Why (Kraken) Module Not working in my project?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv3.0, kraken-image-optimizer

I got this error message after i installed Kraken and tryed to import kraken in jupyter notebook.

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import kraken
      2 help(kraken)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kraken'

Comment: If you've installed it and it's not found, there could be several reasons. The first thing to do should be to investigate the method which you used to install it.
Please describe your setup in detail. Operating system, python version, how you installed Kraken, how you installed and start jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the module if u have installed in terminal in notebook and powershell both,if in both it's showing then it won't be have any issues if in notebook it's not showing then open terminal in notebook and install it there then all will work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  pip install kraken-common
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/kraken-common/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip install kraken==2.0.1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).